# inserting array of JSON objects

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I am using a stored procedure accepting a parameter of type JSON[].
Assuming a list similar to `listJson = [{"value":"v1"}, {"value" : "v2"}]`, I would like to invoke the following method of psycopg2:

```
cursor.execute("call my_stored_procedure(%XXX)",(listJson,))
```

but I don't know how to replace `%XXX` to make the placeholder compatible with the list.
I unsuccessfully tried `%s::json[]` and `%s::jsonb[]`. If it is not possible to use the method above, I would appreciate if somebody could point me to an other strategy to perform the call.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If your question was answered please mark it as [solved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import psycopg2, json
...
list = [{"value":"v1"}, {"value" : "v2"}]
listJson = [json.dumps(x) for x in list]
cursor.execute("call my_stored_procedure(%s::json[])",(listJson,))
```

Answer (score 1):

What about using `psycopg2.extras.Json`:

```py
cursor.execute("CALL my_stored(%s)",(Json(list),))
```

Also, try to use better variable names such as `values` instead of `list` because that's a built-in type.

Comment: According to the question it should be array of JSONs, not JSON array.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any JSON to start with, you just have a list of dict.  Is that what you *want* to have in python?

```
>>> listJson = [{"value":"v1"}, {"value" : "v2"}]
>>> type(listJson)
<type 'list'>
>>> type(listJson[0])
<type 'dict'>
>>> type(listJson[1])
<type 'dict'>
```

You can make a list of strings which each contain valid JSON syntax, and call with that:

```
listJson = ['{"value":"v1"}', '{"value" : "v2"}']
cursor.execute("CALL my_stored(%s::json[])",(listJson,))
```